# A method to always cc/bcc self in emails sent using Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

The reason I'm asking this- as I know there's a sent folder- is that the account I'm concerned with currently forwards all incoming emails to two managers.  However, this account is used by various student workers who use it to send emails, and the managers would like copies of those emails as well.  We've been asking the student workers to add the email to the bcc field so it forwards proper, but they often forget to do it.

I've previously tried to arrange filters to send to the managers when sending emails, but they don't appear to work.  I'm looking for something within Gmail, or at least would only apply to this single account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Gmail Auto BCC](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/2255) for Greasemonkey.